# Is there a general algorithm to determine the number of distinct prime factors a number has?

Tags: number-theory

I came upon this question when I was trying to look for a general computer approach (better than a brute force approach) to solve the equation,
$\\ \phi(n) = k$ for any given $k$. It could be made a lot faster if there was an easy and efficient way to determine the number of distinct prime factors a number has. Does anyone know if there is a function in number theory that does this, and if there is, what is the most efficient way to calculate it?

Comment: There is a polynomial time primality testing algorithm. Perhaps there is a polynomial time algorithm for your generalization of primality testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many algorithms on [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), but they do not run in polynomial time (only sub-exponential time). So it is possible to determine the number of prime divisors of integers $n$ for a "reasonable size" on $n$. On the other hand, there is a lot known about solving the equation $\phi(n)=k$, where we do not need to know the number of prime divisors of $n$, e.g., see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477336/image-of-the-euler-phi-function) and the references given.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no known such computable function as the numbers get sufficiently large.  For example, it's unknown how many prime factors [googolplex+1](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/GOOGOL.HTM) has, but it's over 14.

Comment: It *is* a [computable function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function): there exists an exponential-time algorithm, e.g., factorize the number with trial division, then count the number of distinct factors.  I suspect this answer is confusing "computable" with "efficiently computable" (e.g., in polynomial time), and even then, we don't have a proof that it can't be done in polynomial time, though there are certainly strong suspicions that it can't be done in polynoimal time.